# Connecting two HP 2910al Switches using SFP to get 2Gb/s speed

Tags: switch, ethernet, trunk, hp, stacking

I would like to Connect my two HP 2910al switches using SFPs to get a maximum of 2G links.

is this possible, and how?

I want to make both of them to use the IP address (ex 192.168.2.xxx).
I have the same Switches as in the Photo, the 48 port Switch is full, that's why I added the 24 port switch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not actual stacking, where multiple switches look like a single switch for management and configurations. What you seem to want is to create a LAG (Link Aggregation Group) between two switches. I believe you can do that with LACP on those switches:

```
trunk ethernet <range_of_ports> trk<trunk_number> lacp
```

Keep in mind that a single flow will only use a single link, but in aggregate among multiple flows, you will get the full bandwidth of the aggregation.

Comment: Yes thanks, I want to make both of them as a single switch with one IP (ex 192.168.2.xxx).
I have the same Switches as in the Photo, the 48 port switch is full, that's why I added the 24 port switch.

Comment: Those switches do not stack. You will need to connect them as separate switches with LAG.

Comment: Do you know how can I make (LAG) for these hp switches? to make them work as one.

Comment: You cannot make them work as one switch, but I put in the command to create the LAG using LACP in my answer. They will be two separate switches, connected with a LAG. I think you would need 2920 switches with a stack module to do what you want.

Comment: Yes Thanks, Ron, now I understand
trunk ethernet <range_of_ports> trk<trunk_number> lacp
in my case, I had Port 45 on Sw1 connected on Port 45on SW2
and SW1 port 46 with SW2 Port46
what is the command for that?

Comment: Something like: `trunk ethernet 45-46 trk1 lacp`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition to Ron's

> Keep in mind that a single flow will only use a single link, but in aggregate among multiple flows, you will get the full bandwidth of the aggregation

2910al switches use simple IP source-address/destination-address (SA/DA) traffic distribution, so all frames between the any two IP endpoints always use the same port combination (for each direction).

Since that distribution is rather random it'll only provide proper load balancing with a larger number of endpoints (or fine-tuned addressing). If that doesn't work out you might need to add 10G modules.

Also note that it doesn't matter speed-wise whether you use twisted-pair copper or SFPs with fiber. Fiber just enables longer reach.

Additionally, "stacking" with the 2910al just means management through a single IP - you can switch the chassis in CLI or the menu. It's not a true stacking in the sense of both switches acting as a single one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments,
(" If that doesn't work out you might need to add 10G modules.")
can I use ´10 G SFPs on this kind of switch, from front?

Comment: No, the front slots are SFP/1G only. 10G SFP+ slots are optional, on the back. Those port modules (J9008A) are easy to find used but ludicrously priced new. You could also use the CX4 interconnect kit (J9165A) if you need neither SFP+ nor more than one port each.